# WooComerce shows blank site (Shop)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

The site I set WooComerce to use as the shop is blank (white), I enabled debuggng mode (`define('WP_DEBUG', true);`) but no errors are shown. I tried to using a new Site for the shop but the same. The rest of the Website works perfectly fine, as does the checkout, and other WooComerce pages.

The '*status*'-tab of the WooComerce-Plugin shows that everything is allright.

I'm pretty new to WooComerce so is there a key setting I'm missing or something? The Shop worked fine a few Weeks ago but I just noticed the blank site.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it. An outdated, Theme spefic Woocomerce Extension caused the Problem. Had to update the files manually... I don't now if it helps someone else but this was the fix for me.